# Have I gone crazy, or has PHP's strototime() broke?

Tags: php, strtotime

**Manual quote:**

> This page describes the different date formats that the strtotime()

> "2008-6-30"

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

**Test code:**

```
var_dump(strtotime('‎2008-6-30'));
var_dump(strtotime('‎2008-06-30'));
```

**Expected output:**

```
(two Unix timestamps)
```

**Actual output:**

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

I literally use the date used as an example in the manual, and even that doesn't work.

I'm 99.9999999999999% sure that it used to work, not long ago.

PHP 7.4.11 @ Windows 10 Pro 2004.

What is wrong?

Comment: You've got a weird hidden character at the beginning of your strings. See [here](https://3v4l.org/MshbX) after copy-pasting. Remove it and you're good to go. (Sorry wrong 3v4l link, edited.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a hidden character in your code, if I copy your code into https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/, there's a red marked char in your string.

If I remove this, it works and prints out a timestamp.